# CAML Query OrderBy ignoring non set values

Tags: caml-query, caml, sorting

I'm currently writing some CAML Query for a QueryOverride in one of my Content Query Web Parts as I'm in need of multiple "Sort by" fields.

My issue is that one of the additional fields that I need sorting on may contain null values which make the query ignore the rows which has a null value and only performs the sort on rows which has a legitimate value.

My CAML Query so far

```
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="ArticleStartDate" Ascending="False" />
    <FieldRef Name="ArticlePriority" Ascending="True" />
</OrderBy>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="FilterMM" />
            <Value Type="TaxonomyFieldType">Company news</Value>
        </Contains>
        <And>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="ArticleStartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime"><Today /></Value>
            </Leq>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="_EndDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime"><Today /></Value>
            </Geq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

`ArticlePriority` is the troublemaker, as not all news have a priority set as they are less important than others which has priority 1,2,3 etc. meaning they should at all times be AFTER the ones with set priorities.

I tried adding `Nullable="True"` to it as I thought that might help but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ArticlePriority` is a choice column then `null` values will be sorted before the ones with values.

One solution could be to create a hidden calculated column with the formular something like `=IF(ArticlePriority=0,9999,ArticlePriority)` and then order by that column

Comment: It's unfortunately not a choice column, it's a number column as the priorities have to be unique values in order to prevent multiple articles having the same priority.

Comment: Then use the formular `=IF(ISNUMBER(ArticlePriority),ArticlePriority,999999)`